# E-commerce like feature for selecting product sizes or color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have searched the whole web to the best of my ability on how to create an interface for selecting products just like the ones implemented in most of the major e-commerce apps(amazon,taobao,shopify..).The goal is to highlight or change the styles of the selected item in the list by simultaneously removing the styles of the previously selected item. I am trying to use react-native to clone such a feature. Any references or guides on how to do this will be highly appreciated!

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text ,StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';

 class Selections extends Component {

    state={
        highlighted: false,
        id: null
    }


// The purpose of this function is to set the state to the target index on press
    indexStateHandler = (i) =>{
         if(this.state.id === null){
             this.setState({
                 id: i
             })
         }else{
             this.setState({
                 id:i
             })
         }
         console.log("index: "+i)
         console.log("state: "+this.state.id)
    }

    //The purpose of this function is to set styles for the targeted index
    highlightStateHandler = (i) =>{     
        if(this.state.id === i){
            if(!this.state.highlighted){
                this.setState({
                    highlighted:true
                })
            }
            else{
                this.setState({
                    highlighted:false
                })
            }
        }  
           }

    highlightHandler = (i) =>{

        // console.log(i)
        this.indexStateHandler(i)
        this.highlightStateHandler(i)

    }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.selectionWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.label}><Text style={{color: "black"}}>{this.props.label}</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        {this.props.options.map((options, i) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.highlightHandler(i)} key={i}>
            <View style={this.state.highlighted&&this.state.id == i?styles.highlighted:styles.options} > <Text style={styles.text}>{options}</Text> </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
              )
        )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    selectionWrapper:{
        width: '100%',
        height: 100,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'red',
    },
    label:{
        flex: 1,

    }
    ,
    listContainer:{
        flex: 3,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        alignItems: 'center',
        // backgroundColor: "#7fffd4"
    },
    options:{
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#d0b783",
        // backgroundColor: ""

    },
    text:{
        color: 'black',
        textAlign: 'center'
    },

    highlighted:{
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        // borderColor: "#d0b783",
        backgroundColor: "#d0b783"

    }
})
export default Selections
```

Comment: 'conditional rendering'

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: render selected style for selected item, not selected for not selected ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
.....
.....
.....

<TouchableOpacity
style={[styles.buttonStyle,{
backgroundColor : item.id === this.state.selectedItem.id ? "red" : "blue"
}]}
>
{
...
...
}
</TouchableOpacity>

.....
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity) and [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight) and try to run examples to see how they work. Also you can combine them to changing visual changes by changing styles.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react' import {   AppRegistry,   StyleSheet,   TouchableOpacity,   Text,   View, } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends React.Component {   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      itemEn1: true,
      itemEn2: false,
      itemEn3: false,
    }   }

  onPress1 = () => {
    this.setState({
      itemEn1: true,
      itemEn2: false,
      itemEn3: false,
    })   } 
onPress2 = () => {
    this.setState({
      itemEn1: false,
      itemEn2: true,
      itemEn3: false,
    })   } 
 onPress3 = () => {
    this.setState({
      itemEn1: false,
      itemEn2: false,
      itemEn3: true,
    })   }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={this.state.itemEn1 ? styles.buttonEnabled : styles.buttonDisabled}
          onPress={this.onPress1}>
          <Text> Item 1 </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={this.state.itemEn2 ? styles.buttonEnabled : styles.buttonDisabled}
          onPress={this.onPress2}>
          <Text> Item 2 </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={this.state.itemEn3 ? styles.buttonEnabled : styles.buttonDisabled}
          onPress={this.onPress3}>
          <Text> Item 3 </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )   } }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
   container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10 
     }, 
    buttonDisabled: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 20 
    }, 
   buttonEnabled: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 20  
     },  
    countContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10 
     },

})
```

this is by map function:

```
export default class DataCollector extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.SendBack = this.SendBack.bind(this);
  }

  SendBack(info) {
    console.log("Key is :", info);
    this.props.callback(info);
  }

  render() {
    let testData = this.props.data.map(function (articleData, index) {
      return (
        <View key={index}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.6}
            key={index}
            onPress={() => this.callBack([articleData.id, articleData.name])}>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )

    }, this);

    return (
      <View>
        {testData}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

so now you have access to the clicked item and can use it for enable/disable etc..

Comment: Nice example here Ali, but what if you plan to display the options(items to select) from an object or an array using the map() function rather than hard coding the options to your environment? How would you now manage to attach states to those options so that when pressed, only the targeted option or options evaluates to true(in the state) and gets the selected option styling while the rest evaluates to false?

Comment: I wanted to share a gif of what i did, but the file was to large. I am going to add in my code for you to see how i approached the problem. Let me know what you think.